# How to convert dictionary keys string to variables(parameters) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my problem is that I need a some variables and parameters which are in string form in dictionary and the values are in both shape (string and integer)
For example :

```
d={'a6':'36','a21':52}
```

Now I want these to use them in next steps in some math formulas:

```
a6=36.0
a21=52.0
```

Is there anyway to change those keys which are in string forms to these variables?

Comment: whats wrong with `d['a6']`?

Comment: You can convert a string to a number using `float`.

Comment: The input data structure, i.e. a dictionary, is precisely the ideal one for what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
for key,val in d.items():
    vars()[key] = int(val)
```

```
>> a6
36
```

Comment: Hmm... why don't I like this?

Comment: I would also keep the dictionary, but if he really needs to have access to the variables directly, it's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line with:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> locals().update(d)
>>> a
1
```

or:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> for key,val in d.items():
        exec(key + '=val')

#list(map(exec, ("{0}={1}".format(x[0],x[1]) for x in d.items())))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    exec("%s = %s" % (k, v))
```

Please note that using exec (or eval) can create a substantial security risk if you don't have complete control over the inputs.